# Retrofit 2 connect to local server, response failure, connection timed out

Tags: android, http, server, get, retrofit

My android app that runs retrofit 2.3 doesn't send my GET request to my HTTP server when I give it an URL with the servers IP address.

I got a correct response from my server when I tried the URL in a browser on my laptop, phone or android studio emulator.

So I added a okHttp interceptor logger so i know whats happening on the network. And it prints this in the log:

```
okHttp log
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://IP/stuffworks?a=7u http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

This is my implementation in the android app (when testing call.enqueue always goes to onFailure and Toasts "error :("

```
//Retrofit network method
private void beemMeUp(String ipAdress, String attributes)
    {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://" + ipAdress + "/")
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        SiloClient client = retrofit.create(SiloClient.class);
        Call<SiloSensorReport> call = client.report(attributes);
        Toast.makeText(this, "https://" + ipAdress + "/" + attributes,                      
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SiloSensorReport>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SiloSensorReport> call, 
        Response<SiloSensorReport> response)
            {
                SiloSensorReport repos = response.body();

                textView.append(repos.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success :)", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SiloSensorReport> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            });
        }

    }
```

The address should be like:

```
http://IPaddress/attribute
```

for example:

```
http://123.45.67.12/stuffworks?works=true&value=87
```

my server code

```
server.on("/stuffworks", stuffHandler);


void stuffHandler()
{
  Serial.println("User requesting stuffworks page!");

String message = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++)
  {
    Serial.print(server.argName(i));
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(server.arg(i));
    message += server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i);
    message += "<br>";
  }

  server.send(200, "text/plain", "it works<br>" + message);
}
```

---

P.S.
After changing the URL to use http:// instead https:// i saw my server printing that it got a GET request and also getting a response back on the client caught with the okHttp logger.

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.43.223/stuffworks?a=val http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.43.223/stuffworks?a=val (50ms)
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 22
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: it works, a: val
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (22-byte body)`
```

But I still have a problem where the call.enqueue always goes to onFailure and prints error :( even though i got a server response

Comment: Is it supposed to be http or https?

Comment: is that an online server or localhost?

Comment: Napster you beautiful bastard. ITS HTTP XDDDDDDDDD

Thank you :*

Comment: its a local server loaded on a small microcontroller with a ESP8266 wifi module.
Doing a project with a friend to make an app to measure a furnace with a load of sensors

Comment: So i tested it with a few attributes and the server responds back, but **call.enqueue** goes to **onFailure** and still prints out error :(


the okHttp logger logs


`D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.43.223/stuffworks?a=wer http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.43.223/stuffworks?a=wer (50ms)
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 22
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: it works<br>a: wer<br>
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (22-byte body)`

Comment: In the Failure portion - If  `Throwable` is `IOException`, the problem is with your network. If its not there must be something wrong with serializing or de-serializing the data.

Comment: I don't get any exceptions when I run my code. Which is frustrating since I don't know how to debug it

Comment: If `onFailure()` is being called, Its means there is an exception. It can be your network problems, or Data parsing errors. Check if it is Network error using `t instanceOf IOException`.

Comment: t is instance of IOException